Validate proof for $A \Rightarrow B, (C \vee \neg A) \Rightarrow F, B \Rightarrow D, \neg D \vDash F$
I have the following premises:
$$A \Rightarrow B, (C \vee \neg A) \Rightarrow F, B \Rightarrow D, \neg D$$
I attempted to construct a proof for the conclusion $F$ using inference rules, but I'm not sure if my proof is correct. Here is the proof I came up with:

$B \Rightarrow D$: Premise 1 (P1)
$\neg D$: Premise 2 (P2)
$\neg B$: Modus tollens on P1 and P2
$A \Rightarrow B$: Premise 3 (P3)
$ \neg A$: Modus tollens on 3. and P3
$ (C \vee \neg A) \Rightarrow F $: Premise 4 (P4)
$ \neg (C \vee \neg A) \vee F $: Implication elimination in 6.
$ (\neg C \wedge \neg \neg A) \vee F $ DeMorgan Law
$ (\neg C \wedge A) \vee F $ : Double negation in 8.
$ F \vee (\neg C \wedge A) $ : Commutativity law
$ (F \vee A) \wedge (F \vee \neg C) $ : Distributivity law
$ F \vee A $ & $\wedge$-elimination through simplification rule
$ F $: Disjunctive syllogism of 12. and 5. $(\neg A)$
$ F $: Conclusion

Is this proof correct?
Any suggestions or corrections would be appreciated!

How about you say anywhere up front what you are trying to prove. It makes it a lot easier to read a proof if you know the goal. And the title is wrong - the proof is not "of" the premises.

Maybe after step 5 Addition will be useful: from $\lnot A$ to $C \lor \lnot A$.

Note that technically, your proof should be a semantic one since you use $\vDash$ as opposed to $\vdash$. Otherwise, it looks fine.
